# Не могу подключиться из docker-контейнера к postgresql-базе данных, расположенной на другом компьютере в локальной сети

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, lan

Есть контейнер docker с nodejs, которому необходимо подключение к БД postgresql.

Docker с запущенными контейнерами расположен в локальной сети по адресу 168.192.0.100.
База данных расположена в этой же локальной сети, по адресу 168.192.0.101.

Сама база данных настроена слушать все сети и вещать на все сети.

С помощью pgAdmin могу с компьютера, на котором запущен docker (168.192.0.100) подключиться к БД (168.192.0.101), но из самого docker-контейнера не могу.

Пробовал использовать `--network host`, но это не помогло.

Сам по себе образ докера запускаю такой командой:

`docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 5432:5432 image_name`

Перед этим, собирал его из Dockerfile.

Содержимое Dockerfile

````
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8081
EXPOSE 5432```
````

Comment: Даже не подсказка, но не могу промолчать. Зачем вы используете в локальной сети адреса подобные 168.192 ... ? Есть ведь определенный список сетей для "внутреннего" использования. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

По факту же вопроса - каким образом вы пытаетесь подключится из контейнера - тоже не очень понятно.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, проблема была  том, что использовал самую новую версию nodejs 14.2 и на ней пакет для работы с postgresql pg не работал. т.е. даже ошибки не выдавал, а просто никак не работал. Перешел на nodejs 12.6.3 и все заработало нормально. Касательно сетей. Про соглашения о том, что определенные сети отданы, под определенные задачи помню, но поскольку локальная сеть дома и состоит всего из пары устройств с корректной настройкой особо не заморачивался, ибо просто смысла тратить время на это нет, но спасибо, что заметили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была испралена, путем перехода на более раннюю версию nodejs (12.6.3). На последней версии nodejs (14.2.0), пакет для работы с postgresql pg, не работал. т.е. даже ошибок никаких не выводил.